# Can Rechart components be loaded with React.lazy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to implement code splitting, but some components aren't working. From the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html), the components must be from `export default`, and these are. I also tried exporting them in my own file as default, but it did not work.

Here is an example component. A couple components were able to be split, the rest do not render if I try to do so.

```js
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react'
import {
  Bar,
  CartesianGrid,
  Legend,
  Tooltip,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
} from 'recharts'
const BarChart = lazy(() => import('recharts/lib/chart/BarChart'))
const ResponsiveContainer = lazy(() => import('recharts/lib/component/ResponsiveContainer'))

const barAxisTick = ({ x, y, payload }) => {
  return (
    <g transform={`translate(${x},${y})`}>
      <text dy={16} textAnchor="middle" fill="#666">{payload.value}</text>
    </g>
  )
}

const StackedBarChart = ({ data, height }) => (
  <Suspense fallback={<div style={height}></div>}>
    <ResponsiveContainer height={height.height} id="timeline">
      <BarChart data={data} margin={{ top: 16, right: 32, left: 8, bottom: 5 }}>
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis dataKey="name" tick={barAxisTick} />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Bar dataKey="Collected" stackId="a" fill="#1976d2" />
        <Bar dataKey="Due" stackId="a" fill="#d32f2f" />
      </BarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  </Suspense>
)

export default StackedBarChart
```

Comment: I found it easy and effective to put my chart into a component (with all the references to reChart) and then make my component lazy. As opposed to trying to make the rechart components lazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const BarChart = lazy(() => import('recharts').then(module => ({ default: module.BarChart })));
const ResponsiveContainer = lazy(() => import('recharts').then(module => ({ default: module.ResponsiveContainer })));
const Bar = lazy(() => import('recharts').then(module => ({ default: module.Bar })));
const XAxis = lazy(() => import('recharts').then(module => ({ default: module.XAxis })));
const YAxis = lazy(() => import('recharts').then(module => ({ default: module.YAxis })));
const CartesianGrid = lazy(() => import('recharts').then(module => ({ default: module.CartesianGrid })));
const Tooltip = lazy(() => import('recharts').then(module => ({ default: module.Tooltip })));
const ReferenceLine = lazy(() => import('recharts').then(module => ({ default: module.ReferenceLine })));
```

recharts does not have export default, so you have to import like this

Comment: Works also for other heavy components, e.g., from nivo charts

`const ResponsivePie = lazy(() => import("@nivo/pie").then((m) => ({ default: m.ResponsivePie })));`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that currently, loading components from recharts lazy does not work very well https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/2566